# How much memory does Array[Byte] occupy in Scala?

Tags: scala, memory, arrays

In `Scala 2.10`, I create a stream, write some text into it and take its byte array:

```
val stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
// write into a stream
val ba: Array[Byte] = stream.toByteArray
```

I can get the number of characters using `ba.length` or `stream.toString().length()`. Now, how can I estimate the amount of memory taken by the data? Is it `4 (array reference) + ba.length (each array cell occupies exactly 1 byte) - and this is in bytes`?

Comment: Why are you asking this question? If your program is hitting memory limits and you are wondering whether to change parts of it that use `Array` to use something else, you would do much better to use a profiler to see which parts are actually using memory than trying to guess. And such a profiler would make it easy to confirm whether any changes you made were improvements or not.

Comment: @lmm maybe he was just curious if scala arrays box primitives. Scala collections *do* box primitives, so it is not that far-fetched.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It occupies exactly as much memory as in java. Scala arrays **are** java arrays.

```
scala> Array[Byte](1,2,3).getClass
res1: java.lang.Class[_ <: Array[Byte]] = class [B
```

So the memory usage is the size of the array plus some little overhead that depends on the architecture of the machine (32 or 64bit) and the JVM.

To precisely measure the memory usage of a byte array on the JVM, you will have to use an java agent library such as [JAMM](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm).

Here is a scala project that has JAMM set up as a java agent: https://github.com/rklaehn/scalamuc_20150707 . The build sbt shows how to configure JAMM as an agent for an sbt project, and there are some example tests [here](https://github.com/rklaehn/scalamuc_20150707).

Here is some example code and output:

```
val mm = new MemoryMeter()
val test = Array.ofDim[Byte](100)
println(s"A byte array of size ${test.length} uses "+ mm.measure(test) + "bytes");

> A byte array of size 100 uses 120 bytes
```

(This is on a 64bit linux machine using oracle java 7)